# Measurable set of points where a measurable sequence fails to converge

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions. Prove that the set of points $x$ such that $\{f_n(x)\}$ fails to converge as $n\to\infty$ is measurable.

My first attempt was

Suffices to show that the set of points $x$ such that $\{f_n(x)\}$ converges as $n \to\infty$ is measurable. The set we want is the complement of that set, hence it is measurable. So suppose $\{f_n : n \in \mathbb Z_+\}$ is any sequence of measurable functions on a measurable space $(X,M)$. For each $x \in X$, the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}$ converges as $n\to \infty$ iff it is a Cauchy sequence. So, for each  $\epsilon > 0 $ and pair $n, m \in \mathbb Z_+$, define $$Y_{nm}(\epsilon) = \{x \in X : |f_n(x) − f_m(x)| <\epsilon\}.$$ These are all measurable sets, since $|f_n(x) − f_m(x)|$ is a measurable function for measurable $f_n, f_m$. Now construct the measurable sets $$\begin{aligned}Y_N(\epsilon )&=\bigcap_{m\ge N}Y(N_m )(\epsilon ), N\in\mathbb Z^+,\\ Y(\epsilon)&=\bigcup_{N\in \mathbb Z^+}Y_N (\epsilon)\end{aligned}.$$ Then $$\begin{aligned}x \in Y (\epsilon) &\implies (\exists N)\colon x \in Y_N (\epsilon) \\&\implies (∃N)(\forall m \ge  N)\colon |f_N (x) − f_m(x)| < \epsilon \\&\implies (\exists N)(\forall n, m \ge N)\colon |f_n(x) − f_m(x)| < 2 \epsilon \end{aligned}$$ Thus we get a measurable set of points of convergence by taking the intersection over a countable decreasing sequence of epsilons tending to 0, such as: $Y = \bigcap_{k\in \mathbb Z^+}Y(1⁄k)$; $x\in Y$; this  implies $f_n(x)$ converges as $n\to\infty $. It remains to show that all points of convergence lie in $Y$. If $\{f_n(x)\}$ converges, then $x \in Y(\epsilon)$ for every $\epsilon> 0$. But $$0<\epsilon_1<\epsilon_2\implies Y_(\epsilon_1 )\subset Y_(\epsilon_2 )\implies \bigcap_{\epsilon>0}Y(\epsilon)=\bigcap_{k\in \mathbb Z^+}Y(1⁄k)$$ so $\{f_n(x)\}$ converges iff $x \in Y$.

Comment: What did you try? Personally, I would start with the fact that, for any $m$, $n$, and $\varepsilon>0$, the set $\{x\colon |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\ge\varepsilon\}$ is measurable. Do you see how that could be useful? (And do you see why it is *true*?)

Comment: Alternatively, the set $E$ on which $\{f_n\}$ does converge must be measurable. Since the collection of measurable sets is a $\sigma$-algebra, we must have that $E^c$ is measurable.

Comment: see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881548/set-of-points-at-which-sequence-of-measurable-functions-converge-another-approa/881586#881586)

Comment: I wrote up a proof for this on my blog not too long ago [here](http://alexschiff.blogspot.com/2014/06/western-michigan-universitys-2013b.html).

Comment: My attempt for proof was like this

Comment: I TeXified your attempted proof, check that it still says what you meant.

Comment: Thank you for TeXifying my proof. That is what I had in mind

Comment: I edited the post further for readability. In the process, I found that the long chain of implications did not make any sense, so I rewrote it to make sense (to me). Perhaps there was significance in the two styles of implication arrows ($\implies$ and $⇒$); I don't know. My apologies if the edit went too far. (And now I don't have time left over for careful reading; but a cursory glance says it looks reasonable, if perhaps a bit clumsy in parts.)

Comment: Just choice of notation. Any way thank you for the review.